# Can not connect to JFrog Artifactory API

Tags: timeout, artifactory

I've setup an Artifactory on a Free plan for now, and so far we host 2 Python packages.

Yesterday I had no troubles making operations through the API or resolving dependencies but since this morning, nothing is working.

This is the kind of errors I get with a `pip install mypackage` :

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f44286929e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/mypackage/

Same kind of behavior when I try to create a service token through the API, my cURL request just won't resolve.

If I check the service and access logs it seems that my requests are accepted but are not processed afterward.

Any hints on what I can do? As there is no "restart services" options, at least that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it had nothing to do with JFrog.

My WSL config is messed up and the network is down on it...

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: To add to the answer : I don't know what really happened, but I am working on a Debian with WSL and the first thing I tried this morning was what I described in the original post, trying to fetch packages and make API calls. I thougth my Artifactory API was down because I had no internet issue on the host system (being Windows). Turns out I wanted to do something else and I understood the network was messed up on my WSL instance. I rebooted my machine and it worked again flawlessly.